# Laplace transformations and Convolutions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

This question is question number 37 of Apostol's *Mathematical Analysis*.

Show that the convolution $h=f\ast g$ assumes the form $h(t)=\int_{0}^{t} f(x) g(t-x) \;\mathrm dx$ where both $f$ and $g$ vanish on the negative real axis. Use convolution theorem for Fourier Transforms to prove that $\mathcal L(f*g)= \mathcal L(f)\cdot \mathcal L(g)$.

I proved that $h=f\ast g$ assumes the form $h(t)=\int_{0}^{t} f(x) g(t-x) \;\mathrm dx$. but I am unable to get ideas on how to prove that $\mathcal L(f\ast g)= \mathcal L(f)\cdot \mathcal L(g)$.

Here LHS will be given by $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-zt} \int_{0}^{t} f(x) g(t-x) \;\mathrm dx \;\mathrm dt $ but how to prove it as given in the RHS? Any hints.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, change of variables are very useful in this proof, i.e. $y=t-x$ and change the order of integration (consider why you're allowed to do this).